# Why can microwave (in microwave oven) heat the food but wifi can't?

Tags: radio-frequency, microwaves

As far as i know, microwave (used in microwave oven) and wifi all operate on the same frequency, but why microwave can heat the foods while wifi wave can't?

Comment: It's just a mater of power.  Microwave ovens put out much more power.